# Coffeescript: how to link div, but override link if child links are clicked

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I find it hard to explain, so please request more info if you need it.

I have a div like so:

```
<div id="clickable">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <a href="google.com" class="link">Google</a>
  <a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</div>
```

I want the div to be clickable, and link to the href of an attribute with class 'link'. This part I have done:

```
  $('#clickable').on 'click', (ev) ->
    window.location = $(this).find('.link').attr('href')
    return false
```

But, what should happen is if a user clicks a link within the div, that links location takes precedence. So, in the above example, if you click yahoo it will direct to yahoo. At the moment, it forces google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to update `window.location` and subsequent `return false` (stopping the click's propagation) is happening regardless of the normal behaviour of a link.

Try this:

```
$('#clickable').on('click', (ev) ->
  unless $(ev.target).is('a')
    window.location = $('.link', @).attr('href') 
    false
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of event bubbling. Click on `a` bubbles to `div` and a `click` handler fires on `div` which redirects you to `.link`. Since the JavaScript is single-threaded, then the top handler is fired as the last one and you are always redirected to `.link`.

Try adding this code:

```
$('#clickable').on 'click', 'a', (ev) ->
    ev.stopPropagation()
```

Don't forget about `'a'` part, which filters click to `a` elements. You can use jQuery's filters there.

**EDIT**

Since for unknown reasons the snippet I posted is not working for you, then how about this? (this time replace the code)

```
$('#clickable').on 'click', (ev) ->
    if ev.target.href
        window.location = ev.target.href
        return
    window.location = $(this).find('.link').attr('href')
    return false
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this doesn't adhere to my requirements. The whole div should be clickable. If I just wanted links to be clickable I wouldn't use js at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zenph I wrote "add this code", not "replace". Add **both** lines.

Comment: I have also added this code. But doesn't work as you are now filtering all 'a' elements, and so the main div does not trigger. Even if I remove ev.stop... and just add the 'a' filter, if I click somewhere in the div which isn't a link, nothing happens.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why the first piece of code doesn't work. Like you say 'filters click to a elements', but the containing div is not an 'a' element and so the event is not triggered by clicking say 'p' elements, is it?

Comment: @Zenph The `x.on` method with a given additional filters searches whether the target of event matches the filter. Basically it is doing more or less the same what I've posted in my second idea. But strangely it isn't in your case.

Comment: @Zenph May it be some other thing that is breaking the code for you? [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeDBv/2/show/) showing the original code working (remove the /show to edit).

Comment: Ahh yes, I see the problem. Didn't realize I need a whole new event to capture this. Thanks for the solution freakish +1.

Comment: @Zenph That's what I've meant when I said "add **both** lines". :D Well, the most important thing is that you know how to fix it. Good luck!