# Haml with Rails: making a table column into a link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm creating a haml table like so:

```
%tbody
  - @records.each do |br|
    %tr
      %td.name
        = br.full_name
      %td.address
        = br.address
```

I would like to create a link from the entire `tr` to another page. How can I do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945620/making-a-table-row-into-a-link-in-rails/10401736#10401736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the row as a block to `link_to`:

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  #row
end
```

EDIT:

```
- link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  %tr
    %td.name
      = br.full_name
    %td.address
      = br.address
```

EDIT BY OP:
this ended up working:

```
  %tr
    %td.name
      = link_to(br.full_name, html_options = {:action => 'show', :id => br.id})
```

Comment: I get this: `Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.` This is haml, not ruby

Comment: This will generate invalid html. Nesting a `<tr>` withing an `<a>` tag is illegal.

Comment: for some reason that shows nothing at all. If i change the - to a = before link_to, then it displays what it did before -- still no link.

Comment: @iblue is correct that the generated html is invalid. It would break the table structure `<table><tr><td /></tr></table>`. You need some alternative

Comment: Is it illegal but supported in some browsers? Just curious. When I provided my answer to the question referenced above I tested the code (Firefox 12ish), which nested the row in an anchor tag, and it worked just fine.

Comment: @maxko87 I was under the impression you wanted the entire row linked, not just a single cell in the row.

Comment: it's not ideal, but I looked around more, and didn't see a way to make the entire row linked in haml (it's doable with jquery). thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Because nesting any block level element inside an `<a>` tag is illegal. I would do it using jQuery.

```
%tr{"data-link" => url_for(:action => 'show', :id => br.id)}
  %td.name
    = br.full_name
  %td.address
    = br.address
```

Then, at the end of the table:

```
:javascript
  $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.location = this.data("link")
  })
```

You should also include a stylesheet that changes the mouse cursor to a pointer.

```
:stylesheet
  #yourtable tr
    cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in Rails 4.0.2. My controller's name is `order`.

Assign an id to your table so you can identify it via CSS later; I used the id `orders`.

For each table row that contains a data cell, add the "data-link" attribute to it with the value of the link (in my case it looks like `/orders/1` and so on).

```
app/views/orders/index.html.haml
```

---

```
%table#orders
  %tr
    %th ...
    .
    .
    .
  - @orders.each do |order|
    %tr{"data-link" => order_path(order)}
      %td= ...
      .
      .
      .
```

In your JavaScript file (or CoffeeScript file as shown here), create the links for the table rows that have the "data-link" attribute with their respective "data-link" values.

```
app/assets/javascripts/order.js.coffee
```

---

```
$ ->
  $("tr[data-link]").click ->
    window.location = @dataset.link
```

In the stylesheet for your controller, make the cursor change into a pointer when hovering over the rows to indicate that they are clickable.

```
app/assets/stylesheets/order.css.scss
```

---

```
#orders tr[data-link] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```