# Row in table is a link but delete link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In this topic:

[Making a table row into a link in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945620/making-a-table-row-into-a-link-in-rails/22456128#22456128)
I found solution to have a row in table that is a link. But with this solution is little problem.
My index.html.haml:

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered#car_configurations
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{width: "10%"}=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.photo')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.brand')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.model')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.body_style')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.car_class')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.cases')
      %th
  %tbody
    - @car_configurations.each do |car_configuration|
      %tr{"data-link" => edit_admin_car_configuration_path(car_configuration)}
        %td= image_tag car_configuration.image_url(:thumb).to_s
        %td= car_configuration.brand.name
        %td= car_configuration.model.name
        %td= car_configuration.body_style.name
        %td= car_configuration.car_class.name
        %td= cases(car_configuration)
        %td
          = link_to ('x'), admin_car_configuration_path(car_configuration), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Jesteś pewien"}, class: "delete"
= link_to t('car_configurations.index.add'), { action: :new }, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

In my js.coffee file I have:

```
$("tr[data-link]").click ->
    window.location = @dataset.link
```

The problem is that when I click my delete link for a moment shows a javascript popoup and then it redirect me to the edit path and I can't delete object. Is there any solution for that?

EDIT:

Thank's for help. Now the destroy link is working but when i click row in table it redirect me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/undefined
```

rather than:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/car_configuration/1/edit
```

My index.html.haml looks like this:

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered#car_configurations
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{width: "10%"}=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.photo')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.brand')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.model')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.body_style')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.car_class')
      %th=t('car_configurations.car_configuration.cases')
      %th
  %tbody
    - @car_configurations.each do |car_configuration|
      %tr{"data-link" => edit_admin_car_configuration_path(car_configuration)}
        %td= image_tag car_configuration.image_url(:thumb).to_s
        %td= car_configuration.brand.name
        %td= car_configuration.model.name
        %td= car_configuration.body_style.name
        %td= car_configuration.car_class.name
        %td= cases(car_configuration)
        %td{class: "delete"}=link_to ('x'), admin_car_configuration_path(car_configuration), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Jesteś pewien"}
= link_to t('car_configurations.index.add'), { action: :new }, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Well the Javascript is the problem. You can't both a) redirect to an edit page and b) go to the delete page. Pick one.

Comment: post some jQuery code which you tried.

Comment: My jquery code is in my post. So there is no solution to this problem?

Comment: You do not have pure Js in your code. `-> window.location = @dataset.link` is not JavaScript. Anyway, use a link with an HREF to go to where you want and then redirect. There is no reason to use JavaScript to change location if you need to do something on the server too

Comment: Yes because I'm using coffescript. Sorry but I still don't know how to resolve this problem...

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you want to popup something, then do the redirect in the callback from the popup buttons

Comment: Thank's everyone for help, I decided to not use this feature because it's complicate something that must be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is almost certainly the problem here

```
1. You're using a Ruby variable in JS
2. You're only sending one "link" request (can't be edit & delete)
```

I would do something like this:

```
 %td{class: "delete"}=
   link_to ('x'), admin_car_configuration_path(car_configuration), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Jesteś pewien"}

$("tr[data-link]").on "click", "td:not(.delete)", ->
    window.location = $(this).parent().data("link")
```

Comment: I've updated my post. Can you look at it and help me solve this problem?

Comment: THat problem will be with how you're loading the link. It will be caused by you not using `parent()`, let me update