# How to make tr clickable over link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make `<tr>` clickable with code like this:

```
<tr <%= link_to 'Show', show_account_employees_path(account), :remote => true %>>
```

I found solution only for direct link without remote.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please describe it a bit more in detail.

Comment: I need smth like this: <tr <%= link_to 'Show', show_account_employees_path(account), :remote => true %>>

Comment: @АртемЯрмилко you want a link inside tr?

Comment: I need all row be clickable

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945620/making-a-table-row-into-a-link-in-rails

Comment: Yes, I saw this solution, but I didn't find how to do it whit 'Remote'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to your comment `I need all row be clickable`

**You can't have a tr inside an anchor tag**. It's invalid HTML to have any elements other than thead,tbody as a direct child of a table. **You'll have to place your anchor tag inside a td or th to be valid.**

**FIX**

If you want entire row to be clickable then you'll have to use js magic, you can do something like:

Use HTML5 data-attribute to get your link value

```
<tr data-href= "<%= show_account_employees_path(account) %>">
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Don't know what exactly you are trying to accomplish by making an ajax request to show an employee but since you want it so you can make it an ajax request using [`jquery's ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method

```
$(document).on("click", "#table-id tr", function() {
  var link  = $(this).data("href")
  $.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "GET"
  });
});
```

Comment: The [`<table>` content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) is slightly more complicated than just `<thead>` and `<tbody>` but yes, you can't put an `<a>` as a direct child of a `<table>` so you have to do it through JavaScript.

Comment: @Mandeep - thanks!!! Works) I only changed `var link  = this.data("href")` to `var link  = $(this).data("href")`

Comment: @yaartem yeah my bad I forgot that