# Clickable row in table can be used only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I was looking for a way to make table row clickable.

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945620/making-a-table-row-into-a-link-in-rails), but it has one quite bad bug. It only lets you open link once. Even if you're redirected, and then you press "back" button, you can't click again.

> I personally would put an `onclick` event on the `tr` using jQuery.
>   The `tr` element would look like this:
>
> ```
> <tr data-link="<%= edit_scout_path(scout) %>">
>    ...
> </tr>
> ```
>
> And then the associated JavaScript (placed in a file such as
>   `app/assets/javascripts/scouts.js`) would be something like this:
>
> ```
> $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
>   window.location = this.data("link")
> })
> ```
>
> This would make all `tr` elements that have a `data-link` attribute
>   act as if they were URLs in the most unobtrusive way I can think
>   possible.

Only thing that makes it work again is refreshing site, which is really frustrating.

Do you know how may I fix this issue?

Comment: It should work on back button.

Comment: I suspect that you're not waiting until a load or pageready event before attaching the click handler to your `tr` elements.

Comment: What do you mean? When I am using browsers' "previous site" button, it works as it should, but when I am using self-made button, that only redirects to previous site, it doesn't work. `<%= link_to t(:back), current_user, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I may have no idea what I am talking about.

I made a random quote machine that was giving me the same problem you mentioned. I could only click on the "generate random quote" button once. To click on it again I'd have to reload the page. What I did that fixed it was taking out the `.onclick(function()` and replaced it with `.on("click", function() {`

Maybe give that a try

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using turbolinks? If the answer is yes, try using:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load'
```

worked for me...